# LED Ceiling Light - Permanently on i.e. switch not working

Tags: electrical

Installing 2x LED ceiling lights and one has worked seamlessly the other not so much...

1st ≈ A straight forward single 3 core wire LNE. Connected L & N to LED driver (no earth required). Single switch to that room and it successfully controls the new light.

2nd = The problem light for me so far...2 x 3 core wires LNE. I have tested and marked the switch Live. The switch to these lights is a 2 gang. The other switch operates it's lights as normal and I even went so far as to switch these around to test the switch I needed was still working given I had tripped the lights on a few occasions.

LED driver only needs a L&N connection.

I can't even fathom how many different combinations of connections I have made :(. None of them result in the light working as normal from the switch.

Anyhow, I am now left with lights permanently on and controlling from the fuse box as I have lost natural light for the evening.

I am in the UK very old house wires are red, black & green/yellow.

Grateful for any advice. Crossing fingers for overnight solution so I can get these cracked in the morning ideally.

Comment: It sounds like a switch loop.  Power at the light goes to the switch then back to the light.  Does the switch only have a single cable(L plus N)?

Comment: Not sure if the UK does this, but US would connect switch N to Power L, switch L to light L and light N to power N.

Comment: We just had a very similar question, but based on wire colors that one was US/Canada, and I don't know the rules for switch loops, colors, etc. in UK.

Comment: Two into the switch. For ceiling, the back of switch has RED to COM and BLACK to L1. For wall lights the RED is to COM and BLACK to L2

Comment: Pictures of the wiring at the light and switch for both the working & non-working ones would be helpful. Also, post the ones you took of the old fixtures these are replacing before you disconnected them. You can [edit] those right into your question - use the site's own hosting provider, makes it easier on everyone, including you.

Comment: @FreeMan lost light for the day and so I'll need to do pictures tomorrow. Unfortunately first fitting was so straight forward I was too blasé and didn't take pictures of original wiring on 2nd...despite additional wires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UK power for lighting is in the ceiling not in the wall, so your 2nd light has power in, power down through the switch & [often] power onward to other fixtures, or even other rooms.

Have a look at this diagram - I've had to re-draw it because, sadly, the site it came from, which had every type of variant of this in an easy-to-understand form, has gone & all I had previously saved was the two-way version :(
This shows a setup with a standard UK ceiling rose… which I'm guessing you removed. If it's still in place, then all you need are the drops marked in brown & blue to your light's live & neutral.

[image]

As you have only 2 cables in the ceiling, then you are likely at the end-point of that particular circuit [lighting circuits are not rings like sockets are], so you are missing 'B' in the diagram & only need concern yourself with 'A' & 'C'.

Although the diagram shows the switched live black neatly taped with a red marker for identification, in practise this never happens. With the power off [of course] you need to get a multimeter/continuity tester on each red/black pair & see which is the switched pair. After that, the rest is just following the diagram - use a bit of 13A terminal block if you don't have easy access to bus-bars or a proper rose.

BTW, whether you choose L1 or L2 on a single-way circuit is so you can pick whether up or down is 'on' without turning the switch over. Switches are almost always pre-wired for 2-way operation [it's probably cheaper to just make them all the same], so you can use either 'way', the switch just alternates between the two, connecting in turn to Com.

Comment: How thoroughly logical... Once I had 'lost' myself simply rolling everything back to when it worked before makes so much sense.

Thankfully I had space above the new light to rewire the rose as shown and simply added a couple of lengths of wire from/to the LED driver. Had I not had the space then the 13A terminal block boxed and pushed into the ceiling would surely have worked too.

All is now working as it should and grateful to @tetsujin for the extensive response and solution.

Comment: Glad you got it. Yes, it is very logical, once you can see the pattern, it's just scary as heck if all you can see are three cables hanging down… & no idea which is which. Once you isolate which is the switched pair, though, the rest just wire in parallel, easy. UK ceiling roses are just the best design ;)